# Environment issue in Angular when try to build

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular8, angular-cli-v8

When I try to build an Angular project I have this issue :

> File '/angular/src/environments/environment.ts' is not a module

I import the file like this :

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

My `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

In my environment folder I have files: `environment.ts`, `environment.prod.ts`, `environment.dev.ts`.

I use NODE_VERSION=10, NG_CLI_VERSION=8

My angular.json, the `build.configurations` for dev :

```
"dev": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "serviceWorker": true
        }
```

Command for build : `"build": "ng build --configuration=dev --aot",`

Please help me. Thanks in advance !

Comment: What command do you use to compile the code? Also, did you think about upgrading to Angular 9 or 10?

Comment: the command : `ng build --configuration=dev --aot`. I can't for now to upgrade

Comment: Then we need angular.json

Comment: At some point cli started to require to include all evnironment replacements candidates in tsconfig (or angular.json cannot remeber) in order to get it to work. It is not enough anymore to just have environment.xxx.ts in env directory.

Comment: @Antoniossss I can confirm this not being the case. Not for Angular 9 at least...

Comment: Show us content of your environment files, the `environment.dev.ts` is probably never referenced, not by default config of angular.

Comment: The content of `environment.ts` ?

Comment: @Akxe I edited my question with angular.json, the configuration build for dev

Comment: try absolute path `import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';` or `import { environment } from 'environments/environment';` depending on your baseHref

Answer (score 1):

Angular by default only configures the `angular.json` production environment to replace the `environement.ts` file. It uses this part of `angular.json`.

```
"configurations": {
   "production":{
      "fileReplacements":[
         {
            "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
         }
      ],
      "rest": ...
   }
}
```

Not for dev to use `environment.dev.ts` you would need to add the `fileReplacements` part to dev build too.

```
"fileReplacements":[
  {
    "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with":"src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
  }
]
```

Or place your dev config to the non-post-fixed one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to export the environment variable with the export keyword:

```
export const environment = {
  ...
}
```